# How can I test EVERY link on the WEBSITE with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I want to test every link on a WEBSITE. I googled a lot but there were only solutions to test every link on a WEBPAGE.

How I wanted to do it:
If the script clicks on a link, the script looks on the new webpage if there is a new link. If there is a new link then the script clicks it and repeats the steps(look and click) untill he cannot find a link. In that case the script navigates back until he finds a new link to click.

Does anyone have a solution for me? I am using Java.

Comment: Please provide atleast a minimal example of your work for the community to support you : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I think using jsoup library is a better choice for this purpose than to navigate via UI using Selenium.

For more info please follow this tutorial : https://www.javatpoint.com/jsoup-tutorial  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    for link in links:
        try:
            response = requests.head(link.get_attribute('href'), allow_redirects=True)
            assert response.status_code in (200, 201, 301, 302, 304, 308)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Broken link detected " + str(link.get_attribute('href')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function to open a link, findElements by Html tag name , and call the function again for each of these links in the list. Be aware that, this can go on for a while, you might run out of memory etc because all web pages normally have links.