# How do I test every link on a webpage with Selenium using Pytho and pytest or Selenium Firefox IDE?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automated-tests, pytest

So I'm trying to learn Selenium for automated testing. I have the Selenium IDE and the WebDrivers for Firefox and Chrome, both are in my PATH, on Windows. I've been able to get basic testing working but this part of the testing is eluding me. I've switched to using Python because the IDE doesn't have enough features, you can't even click the back button.

I'm pretty sure this has been answered elsewhere but none of the recommended links provided an answer that worked for me. I've searched Google and YouTube with no relevant results.

I'm trying to find every link on a page, which I've been able to accomplish, even listing the I would think this would be just a default test. I even got it to PRINT the text of the link but when I try to click the link it doesn't work. I've tried doing waits of various sorts, including
`visibility_of_any_elements_located` AND `time.sleep(5)` To wait before trying to click the link.
I've tried this to click the link after waiting `self.driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, ("lnktxt")).click()`. But none work, not in below code, the below code works, listing the URL Text, the URL and the URL Text again, defined by a variable.

I guess I'm not sure how to get a variable into the By.LINK_TEXT or ...by_link_text statement, assuming that would work. I figured if I got it into the variable I could use it again. That worked for print but not for click()

I basically want to be able to load a page, list all links, click a link, go back and click the next link, etc.

The only post this site recommended that might be helpful was...
[How can I test EVERY link on the WEBSITE with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58039502/how-can-i-test-every-link-on-the-website-with-selenium)
But it's Java based and I've been trying to learn Python for the past month so I'm not ready to learn Java just to make this work. The IDE does not seem to have an easy option for this, or from all my searches it's not documented well.

Here is my current Selenium code in Python.

```
import pytest
import time
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

wait_time_out = 15

class TestPazTestAll2():
  def setup_method(self, method):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.vars = {}

  def teardown_method(self, method):
    self.driver.quit()
  
  def test_pazTestAll(self):
    self.driver.get('https://poetaz.com/poems/')
    lnks=self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
    print ("Total Links", len(lnks))
    # traverse list
    for lnk in lnks:
        # get_attribute() to get all href
        print(lnk.get_attribute("text"))
        lnktxt = (lnk.get_attribute("text"))
        print(lnk.get_attribute("href"))
        print(lnktxt)
    driver.quit()
```

Again, I'm sure I missed something in my searches but after hours of searching I'm reaching out.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I  basically want to be able to load a page, list all links, click a link, go back and click the next link, etc.

I don't recommend doing this. Selenium and manipulating the browser is slow and you're not really using the browser for anything where you'd really need a browser.

What I recommend is simply sending requests to those scraped links and asserting response status codes.

```py
import requests

link_elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
urls = map(lambda l: l.get_attribute("href"), link_elements)
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

(You also might need to prepend some base url to those strings found in href attributes.)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that option. As I mentioned, I'm still learning so I just thought Selenium was used for all the testing.